# How do I translate stack traces from Browserify bundles to the original source code positions?

Tags: javascript, exception, browserify, source-maps

I would like to report stack traces from uncaught exceptions in my JavaScript app, but the problem is that the included JavaScript is a [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) bundle. This means that when I obtain the stack of an exception, it refers to positions within the bundle file, even if the JavaScript bundle contains source maps!

How can I translate the file positions within the stack to the original source files? I guess it involves some use of source maps?

Below is an example program that prints the stack trace of an exception:

### index.html

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

### index.js

```
window.onerror = (message, url, line, column, error) => {
  console.log(`An exception was caught for URL ${url}, line ${line}:`, error.stack)
}

const thrower = () => {
  throw new Error(`Catch me if you can`)
}

const callingThrower = () => {
  thrower()
}

callingThrower()
```

### Generate the Bundle

```
# The --debug flag enables inline source maps
browserify --debug -o bundle.js index.js
```

### Program Output

```
An exception was caught for URL http://localhost:8000/bundle.js, line 7: Error: Catch me if you can
    at thrower (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:7:9)
    at callingThrower (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:11:3)
    at Object.1 (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:14:1)
    at s (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:1:254)
    at e (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:1:425)
    at http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:1:443
```

### Browsers

I've tested with Chrome and Firefox on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

*One* *thing* you can do in your *code* is to enable the **sourcemaps**

*The source maps are the files that tell your browser to translate the line references in your transformed code and the line references in your original code*.

Here is a good link to get an idea of the [sourceMaps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

Enabling the *source maps* is very easy in the *Browserify*.You just have to run

```
browserify --debug main.js -o bundle.js
```

`--debug` tells you to include the *sourceMaps* in the `bundle.js` but to a **disadvantage** it makes your bundle **twice as large**

However you can tell the users to download this file separately by using the plugin [exorcist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exorcist#api) and it will split  the source maps into `bundle.js.map`

For me I add the *browserify* **options** in the `gulpfile.js` as `gruntfile.js` as

```
browserify: {
        dist: {
            src: ['src/main.js'],
            dest: 'dist/bundle.js',
            options: {
                debug: true
            }
        }
    },
```

to enable it or as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/issues/226) you can use `browserifyOptions` instead as

```
options: { browserifyOptions : {} }
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I forgot to mention this in my question, but even if you enable source maps, when you obtain a stack trace programmatically the source maps haven't been applied. That is why I'm asking how to do this.

Comment: ohh then i'll try to find something new

Comment: i just wanted to ask,which browser are you using for this?

Comment: I've tested with Chrome and Firefox, makes no difference.

Comment: There is no gulpfile?

Comment: or where you define the browserify options

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: Are you talking about stack traces specifically, or do you mean debugging in general? Chrome uses the maps to take you to the correct lines in the Sources tab while debugging and such.

Comment: yea ,for the *stacktraces* while bundling there is a need to enable it in the **options** as mentioned above so that it *shows the correct path*,also there are *bugs in chromium unable to get the source maps*  [bug link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145) therefore i don't use it.